# Location: Header not working for one particular trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay, so, I have a PHP and JS-based webapp that does mostly what it's supposed to do. This being said, before I show any code, bear in mind a few things.

1.)The top two location headers inside the 'if' loops work as intended.

2.)In the development tools in Chrome, the location is in the header for this request.

[PasteBin to my code here.](https://pastebin.com/6iMGr19F)

In my JQuery (defined in html head), we see a button name "subAll2", which is supposed to post the intended data, and do a redirect using aforementioned JQuery. The other two redirects work via intended forms. Why does this one not work?

```
$('#subAll2').click(function() {
      var action = $('#frmUser').attr('action');
      $.ajax({
          url  : action,
          type : 'POST',
          data : $('#frmUser, 
#frmUser2').serialize()+"&butSubmitAll=submitAll",
          success : function() {
              window.location.replace(action);
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Obligatory codeblock for requirements. Please check the PasteBin.

Comment: As an added note, the POST variables do work, and the data is, in-fact, thrown into the DB as intended. It's just the redirect that doesn't work.

Comment: As another side-note, Yes, I am aware that standard mysql_ functions are insecure, and I will be going to mysqli_ or pdo_, but for now, please excuse the sloppy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In the JS, replace the success function with

```
success : function(data) {
  if (data == "success")
    windows.location = "list_user.php";
  else
    alert("Form didn't go through.");
}
```

And instead of

```
header("Location:list_user.php");
```

Replace with

```
echo "success";
```

Comment: The reason for this answer has to do with the way the form was submitted. Because AJAX is asynchronous, it basically screwed with the whole thing, and it couldn't be treated the same way. I Hope I've helped someone.

Comment: Done. At least I found the answer on my own.